# FormData function not working

Tags: javascript, function, plugins

So I'm using a plugin for file uploads and I want to use formData to send additional information... but it isn't working.

What I'm trying to do this

```
formData: function(){
              tablenumber = $( this ).data( 'table' );
              var cooldata = {'cod': animeid, 'table': 1};
              alert(JSON.stringify(cooldata));
              return cooldata;
},
```

but it doesn't work. Strangely

```
formData: {'cod': animeid, 'table': 1},
```

works.
The specified type for formData on the plugin is "Type: Array, Object, function or FormData". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the use of `this` in the function might cause problem, as `this` will become a different value at the point of execution by the plugin. You may mitigate this situation by wrapping the function with [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```
formData: (function(obj){
          tablenumber = $( obj ).data( 'table' );
          var cooldata = {'cod': animeid, 'table': 1};
          alert(JSON.stringify(cooldata));
          return cooldata;
    })(this),
```

Comment: the first one worked, but tablenumber was left undefined. the second one didn't pass the formdata, so the $_POST array was left undefined on the php